# Dropdown doesn't work in Angular with Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I've used npm and imported Bootstrap 4 and jquery, popper, etc into my Angular app, but the dropdown in the top nav doesn't work.  I don't want to import a different Angular Bootstrap libraries like ng-boostrap or ngx-boostrap. Why doesn't Bootstrap's dropdown work after you import Boostrap into Angular?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">successfullysell.com</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a routerLink="company/create" class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active">Create Companies</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In angular.json, you need to add below and rebuild.

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ],
```